# what happens if you call an event declared virtual in the header file that is not defined

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to understand a line from [this](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.cpp) code:

```
current->Loop(g_game.time_step);
```

-- where current is a pointer to an object of type State.

In the [header](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.h) file for the state the loop function is declared virtual:

```
virtual void Loop(double time_step) {}
```

But in the [States.Cpp](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/extremetuxracer/code/trunk/src/states.cpp) file the header function is not defined.

What happens if you call a function that is declared but not defined? The code comes from a working open-source game. This line executes without error.

Comment: It is defined. The braces indicate an empty definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function *is* defined; `{}` is the (empty) function body.

`virtual` just means that subclasses *can* override it with virtual dispatch, not that they *must*. To *force* them to do so, you'd make it a "pure" virtual function, by writing `= 0;` instead of `{}`:

```
virtual void Loop(double time_step) = 0;
```

(This would also make the class "abstract", meaning that it can't be instantiated directly.)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a virtual function is both declared and defined.

Just to make it clear - declaration is a function signature that does not have a body, whereas in your case the function has an empty body (`{}`) and thus is being defined.

As for what happens when it is not defined and you call it - you'd get an error during linking stage (which could happen dynamically in case dynamic linking is used).

Answer (score 1):

```
    virtual void Loop(double time_step) {}
```

This line isn't declaring a function, it's defining it.  The function's body is the `{}` whereas a declaration would have `;` at the end instead.

As for what happens, it would fail to link properly, but by recompiling certain parts and not others you can get a symbol lookup error when your program loads the shared library instead.